# How can I set the button text property using a loop?

Tags: vb.net

I want to fill several buttons text from dataset but I dont want to write each command, is there any way to do it?

Here is my code:

```
Sub carga(ByVal boton As Integer)

    Dim consulta() As cocinaDataSet.PRODUCTOSRow
    Dim cantidad As Integer
    consulta = CocinaDataSet.PRODUCTOS.Select()
    cantidad = consulta.Length
    Dim desde As Integer
    desde = (boton - 1) * 60
    Dim hasta As Integer
    hasta = cantidad

    If (desde > cantidad) Then
    Else
        Button1.Text = consulta(desde).NOMBRE
        desde = desde + 1
    End If
    If (desde > cantidad) Then
    Else
        Button2.Text = consulta(desde).NOMBRE
        desde = desde + 1
    End If
    If (desde > cantidad) Then
    Else
        Button3.Text = consulta(desde).NOMBRE
        desde = desde + 1
    End If
    If (desde > cantidad) Then
    Else
        Button4.Text = consulta(desde).NOMBRE
        desde = desde + 1
    End If
    If (desde > cantidad) Then
    Else
        Button5.Text = consulta(desde).NOMBRE
        desde = desde + 1
    End If
    If (desde > cantidad) Then
    Else
        Button6.Text = consulta(desde).NOMBRE
        desde = desde + 1
    End If
    If (desde > cantidad) Then
    Else
        Button7.Text = consulta(desde).NOMBRE
        desde = desde + 1
    End If
    If (desde > cantidad) Then
    Else
        Button8.Text = consulta(desde).NOMBRE
        desde = desde + 1
    End If
    If (desde > cantidad) Then
    Else
        Button9.Text = consulta(desde).NOMBRE
        desde = desde + 1
    End If
    If (desde > cantidad) Then
    Else
        Button10.Text = consulta(desde).NOMBRE
        desde = desde + 1
    End If
    If (desde > cantidad) Then
    Else
        Button11.Text = consulta(desde).NOMBRE
        desde = desde + 1
    End If
    If (desde > cantidad) Then
    Else
        Button12.Text = consulta(desde).NOMBRE
        desde = desde + 1
    End If
    If (desde > cantidad) Then
    Else
        Button13.Text = consulta(desde).NOMBRE
        desde = desde + 1
    End If
    If (desde > cantidad) Then
    Else
        Button14.Text = consulta(desde).NOMBRE
        desde = desde + 1
    End If
    If (desde > cantidad) Then
    Else
        Button15.Text = consulta(desde).NOMBRE
        desde = desde + 1
    End If
    If (desde > cantidad) Then
    Else
        Button16.Text = consulta(desde).NOMBRE
        desde = desde + 1
    End If
    If (desde > cantidad) Then
    Else
        Button17.Text = consulta(desde).NOMBRE
        desde = desde + 1
    End If
    If (desde > cantidad) Then
    Else
        Button18.Text = consulta(desde).NOMBRE
        desde = desde + 1
    End If
    If (desde > cantidad) Then
    Else
        Button19.Text = consulta(desde).NOMBRE
        desde = desde + 1
    End If
    If (desde > cantidad) Then
    Else
        Button20.Text = consulta(desde).NOMBRE
        desde = desde + 1
    End If
    If (desde > cantidad) Then
    Else
        Button21.Text = consulta(desde).NOMBRE
        desde = desde + 1
    End If
    If (desde > cantidad) Then
    Else
        Button22.Text = consulta(desde).NOMBRE
        desde = desde + 1
    End If
    If (desde > cantidad) Then
    Else
        Button23.Text = consulta(desde).NOMBRE
        desde = desde + 1
    End If
    If (desde > cantidad) Then
    Else
        Button24.Text = consulta(desde).NOMBRE
        desde = desde + 1
    End If
    If (desde > cantidad) Then
    Else
        Button25.Text = consulta(desde).NOMBRE
        desde = desde + 1
    End If
    If (desde > cantidad) Then
    Else
        Button26.Text = consulta(desde).NOMBRE
        desde = desde + 1
    End If
    If (desde > cantidad) Then
    Else
        Button27.Text = consulta(desde).NOMBRE
        desde = desde + 1
    End If
    If (desde > cantidad) Then
    Else
        Button28.Text = consulta(desde).NOMBRE
        desde = desde + 1
    End If
    If (desde > cantidad) Then
    Else
        Button29.Text = consulta(desde).NOMBRE
        desde = desde + 1
    End If
    If (desde > cantidad) Then
    Else
        Button30.Text = consulta(desde).NOMBRE
        desde = desde + 1
    End If
    If (desde > cantidad) Then
    Else
        Button31.Text = consulta(desde).NOMBRE
        desde = desde + 1
    End If
    If (desde > cantidad) Then
    Else
        Button32.Text = consulta(desde).NOMBRE
        desde = desde + 1
    End If
End Sub
```

I hope that something like this exists:

```
For f = 1 To consulta.Length
    button & f .text = consulta(f).NOMBRE
Next
```

Comment: You are in the right track, `For... Next` is your way, but you have to reference your buttons so that you can retrieve them orderly along your iteration. Either you can store them in an Array, or you can retrieve them from their parent control's `.Control` property (collection). Try coding it, then, if it doesn't work, put your code attempt here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this may give you what you are after:

```
For f = 1 To consulta.Length - 1

    Dim btn As Button = CType(Me.Controls("Button" & f.ToString()), Button)

    btn.Text = consulta(f - 1).NOMBRE.ToString()

Next
```

This piece of code will find the `Button` control based on `"Button & f"` and will then set the `.Text` property.

Note `consulta(f - 1)`. `consulta` will be zero based and so will start at 0. Since `f` starts at 1 you will need to deduct 1 so you don't miss any of items in `consulta`. I would advise reviewing the indexes by debugging and making sure they match up to what you expect. You may also want to use `consulta.Length - 1`, again because `consulta` is zero based.

Comment: thank you very much, this code resolved my problem. again thank you

Comment: @ElCalefactordeManchuri not a problem. Please consider accepting the answer (tick to the left of the answer)